# Is there somewhere to learn about the possible future of F#?

Tags: f#

Are there any websites/blogs (perhaps by F# team members?) where thoughts about the future of F# are regularly discussed/revealed?

I know of some team members' blogs, but none that I've found contain this type of content.

Comment: Was this closed due to the debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.microsoftpdc.com/

which is broadcast online next week, has as session entitled

```
The Future of F#: Data and Services at your Finger Tips
Don Syme
```

listed.

(We are always thinking about new ideas, but now that we are part of a shipping product (VS2010) with a typical release cadence (every couple years or so), it is likely that we will be a little less transparent in the months just after shipping a major release, as we start to "bake" some new ideas while encouraging people to use the shipped product... as time passes and it becomes time to ship some CTPs/Betas and whatnot, I expect you'll hear more about the future.  Don's talk (and PDC in general) is somewhat forward-looking, I think.)

Comment: ... I didn't realize PDC was so close!  Thanks reminding me!  This session list has me hyped like mad.